# How can I share web-platform credentials across multiple desktop apps on Windows?

Tags: authentication, windows, desktop, secrets-management

I have two desktop apps, each authenticate against our server using OIDC in order to call our web api. Currently the users need to login independently in each application.

I noticed when using Microsoft Office apps on my mac, that I can login to Office365 from Excel, and then, when I open Word, I am logged in.

I guess Microsoft is using Keychain's capability to [share access to keychain items among a collection of apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps).

Is there an equivalent on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Windows has "Credential Manager" (also known as "Password Vault" just to confuse you), which works roughly equivalently to Keychain on Macs. However, software needs to be written to make use of it (same as Keychain!); if you're using software that isn't aware of this feature, it won't do you much good.

The credentials themselves are stored in a per-user location - probably in the user-specific registry hive - and are encrypted using a user-specific key that is protected by the user's login password (same way DPAPI and EFS work; in fact, they might simply be encrypted using DPAPI directly). The encryption is transparent; if you access the credential manager through the GUI or API, your credentials are automatically decrypted for you on read and encrypted for you on write. However, an attacker with access to your machine but not your password won't be able to read your stored credentials, even if they have another Administrator password.

You can access it manually as a user via the "Credential Manager" app, findable from Start search (or from the Control Panel, which yes, still exists on Win11). It's divided into a few categories - "Web Credentials" and "Windows Credentials", the latter of which is subdivided into "Windows Credentials", "Certificate-Based Credentials", and "Generic Credentials" - but as long as your app knows which category to check, "Web Credentials" and "Generic Credentials" are largely the same except that "Web Credentials" remember what app created them. Sandboxed apps - mostly ones from the Windows Store, but also browsers including built-in ones - might not be able to see credentials created by other apps.

If you're writing software yourself, there are a few programmatic ways to access the credentials. The only built-in .NET one I'm aware of is the [PasswordVault class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault), which is designed for UWP apps and probably only supports the WebCredentials store. There's also third-party libraries, such as https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/. Alternatively, you can use the native C/C++ API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/, directly or wrapping it for P/Invoke if using .NET. StackOverflow has more info about this if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Using your pointers I was able to get to the proper documentation. What puzzles me is that according to what you wrote and what I read in the docs, EVERY desktop app has access to the secrets saved by the other....did I get this right?

Comment: If they're running as the same user and not sandboxed, yes. Why does this surprise you? They could just debug one another and pull the secrets directly out of the other process' address space. There's no such thing as an application-level security principal in Windows; it's all user-level (even sandboxed store apps use their "AppContainer" as the principal, and multiple processes running within a container have full access to one another). With minor tweaks, that's true on MacOS and Linux and so on as well; it's the way basically all multi-user operating systems have ever worked.